# onSupportNavigateUp() is not fired anymore after I override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Tags: java, android

***(Sorry for changing the whole question as I found the actual problem after troubleshooting)***
I have my activity as followed:

```
public class MyAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(...)
    {
        //...
        this.setContentView(contentViewResID);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(toolbarResID);

        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {...}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {...}

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        Log.d("onSupportNavigateUp()", "pressed");
        finish();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {...}

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {...}

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item == menuAddFood) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityAddFood.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (item == menuSettings){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySetting.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);

        }
        if(item == menuUsername){
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***
After my troubleshooting, I found out after override the `onOptionsItemSelected()`, `onSupportNavigateUp()` no longer fired anymore when I pressed the top left **BACK / UP / HOME** button. I want to do `finish()` inside `onSupportNavigateUp()` How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `override` the method in your current `Activity` and call the super:

```
public class ActivityExample extends MyAppActivity {

    Context context = this;
    AppCompatActivity activity = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.createMyView(R.layout.activity_log_in, R.id.toolbar);
        // ...
    }

 @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
     finish();
     return true;
    }

}
```

Also, if you override `onOptionsItemSelected`, then `onSupportNavigateUp` will not be called.

```
//DONT OVERRIDE THIS METHOD
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                break;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: I did tried call "super.onSupportNavigateUp()" doen't work either.

Comment: Aren't they both same if override in my current activity or in my super activity?

Comment: what exactly you want to do with the onSupportNavigateUp?

Comment: Sorry FYI, I've changed the whole question. To answer your question, I just want to finish the activity when onSupportNavigateUp() was fired. In normal case, when I pressed BACK button on top left, it should fired the onSupportNavigateUp().